# What differences exist between Objective-C categories and .NET extension methods?

Tags: .net, objective-c, extension-methods, categories

I'm learning about [Categories in Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW1) and they seem *really* similar to [extension methods in .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

Are there any subtle differences or gotchas between the two that can cause problems when moving from one language to the other, or are they for all intents and purposes identical concepts?

Comment: I'm not familiar with extension methods in .NET, but they seem to coincide with my understanding of categories in Objective-C modulo some syntax differences.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience using the two concepts in C# and ObjC, I use the features for the same problems. Adding new instance or static methods to built-in types when subclassing either isn't allowed or ill advised.

I tend to try and avoid Categories/Extensions because they can be a code smell that you are relying on built-in classes too heavily instead of building your own data structures to represent your system.

With that said, I haven't run into any strange gotchas once you understand the syntactical differences.

Answer (score 2):

In the .NET world, an extension method will be called even if the object instance is `null`. For example:

```
public static class Extensions {
    public static string CountCharacters(this string inputString) {
        if (inputString == null) return "None!";
        return inputString.Length.ToString;
    }
}
public void TestExtension() {
    string testString = null;
    string result = testString.CountCharacters(); // returns "None!"
}
```

In the Objective-C world, instance methods defined in a category *will not* be called on an `nil` object instance.

```
@implementation NSString (CountCharacters)
    - (NSString *)countCharacters {
        if (self)
            return [self length];
        return @"None!";
    }
@end
-(void)testCategoryMethod {
    NSString *testString = nil;
    NSString *result = [testString countCharacters];
    // 'result' will remain nil
}
```